# Iterating HashMap with string key

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there a way to iterate through a hashmap in java where the key is a String and a value Is an Integer trying to find the most frequent word that comes up

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. "trying to find the most frequent word that comes up" part is not clear to me

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not understood 'trying to find the most frequent word that comes up'.You can try this.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("k1", 2);
    map.put("k3", 3);
    map.put("k2", 4);
    Set keySet = map.keySet();
    Iterator it = keySet.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) it.next();
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: why iterator if you can run for loop on Set